# How to separate concerns functionally

Tags: functional-programming

I'm writing a program in Scala and trying to remain as functionally pure as is possible. The problem I am facing is not Scala specific; it's more to do with trying to code functionally. The logic for the function that I have to code goes something like:

1. Take some value of type A
2. Use this value to generate log information
3. Log this information by calling a function in an external library and evaluate the return status of the logging action (ie was it a successful log or did the log action fail)
4. Regardless of whether the log succeeded or failed, I have to return the input value.

The reason for returning the input value as the output value is that this function will be composed with another function which requires a value of type A.

Given the above, the function I am trying to code is really of type `A => A` i.e. it accepts a value of type `A` and returns a value of type `A` but in between it does some logging. The fact that I am returning the same value back that I inputted makes this function boil down to an identity function!

This looks like code smell to me and I am wondering what I should do to make this function cleaner. How can I separate out the concerns here? Also the fact that the log function goes away and logs information means that really I should wrap that call in a `IO` monad and call some `unsafePerformIO` function on it. Any ideas welcome.

Comment: If the only purpose of it is to log, it should be `A -> IO ()` not `A -> A`.

Comment: a logging feature doesn't necessarily have anything to do with IO though, you could make use of a Writer Monad perhaps, leaving you with a function of type `A => Writer A`, which you can then do IO operations on

Comment: I have taken @BartekBanachewicz 's advice and changed the function signature to `A -> IO[Unit]`. I then compose the other functions with this IO action monadically in a for expression (equivalent of `do` in Haskell).

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds more like debugging than logging. For example, Haskell's [Debug.Trace.trace](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html) does exactly that and its documentation states: "These can be useful for investigating bugs or performance problems. They should not be used in production code."

If you're doing logging, the logging function should only log and have no further return value. As mentioned by @Bartek above, its type would be `A -> IO ()`, i.e. returning no information `()` and having side-effects (`IO`). For example Haskell's [hslogger library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hslogger-1.2.9/docs/System-Log-Logger.html) provides such functions.